# Comparing two time complexities: SVD vs. LU

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

## Problem

So I have two matrices. Matrix $A$ is a $s \times n$ matrix, while matrix $B$ is a $(n+s)\times (n+s)$ matrix. Both are dense.

To solve a linear system $$ Ax=b$$ SVD is used. On the other hand, to solve $$Bx=b$$ LU decomposition is used.

I want to compare the time complexities.

## Time complexity

Generally speaking, the SVD complexity is (according to a bit of googling) $$\mathcal{O}(s^2n +n^3).$$ Using $s=n/2$ the above finally yields $$\mathcal O (\frac 5 4 n^3).$$
On the other hand, LU decomposition complexity is $$\mathcal O ((n+s)^3).$$ Again using $s=n/2$ yields $$ \mathcal O (\frac{27}{8}n^3).$$

Since I am not very familiar with the big $\mathcal O$ notation, I would be totally happy with that. However, I was given a hint that this approach is by no means valid since, apparently, the the only thing I can conclude from the above is that the time complexity of both is $\mathcal O (n^3)$ ignoring the scalar factors in front.

I was told it would be better to perform such analysis with a full definition of time complexity, hoowever, I can find any.

## Questions

I guess I have two questions:

- Is (based on the equations above) really not valid to conclude that solving the $Bx=b$ system is computationally more complex?
- If yes, where can I find the full time complexities of SVD and LU so I can compare them?

Note: I am using the Eigen library in case that is important.

Comment: Using the Kahan-Golub method, the $(n+s)\times(n+s)$ matrix $\pmatrix{0&A\\A^T&0}$ is transformed to tridiagonal symmetric Hessenberg form by what amounts to simultaneous left and right QR transformations. That alone is, in my guess, equivalent or more expensive than the LU decomposition of $B$. After that follows a numerical iteration to reduce the tridiagonal form to an approximately diagonal one. The complexity here also depends on the desired accuracy of the result.

Comment: Matrix Algorithms from G. W. Stewart had pretty detailed flop analysis of matrix algorithms.